# How to know the replica count of a Spring Boot application in Kubernetes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, partitioning

I have a Spring Boot 2.2.x backend deployed in kubernetes. I want to split a workload in this backend by the number of replicas of this application.
If I have one instance, the range of data (which comes from an external API) must not be split at all. If I have two instances, the first replica must work on the first half of the data and the second replica must work on the other half, and so on.

What is the better way of manage this kind of issue ? Is there a spring library available to dynamically detect the number of instances and partition the data ? I already have a redis avaiblable, I think I can store some useful information in it.

Thanks for you thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spring batch [remote chunking](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html#remoteChunking) pattern to split across multiple processes(each one of the process is a replica pod), communicating with each other through some middleware. Spring batch supports [redis as middleware](https://github.com/Redislabs-Solution-Architects/spring-batch-redis)

[image: remote chunking]

Comment: I do not want to load balance the traffic *to* my backend, I wan't to split an internal workload inside my application. Imagine a scheduled job in my application which use a range of integer from 0 to 100. I wan't this range to be partitioned by the replicas (ie. replica 1 use range 0-50, replica 2 use range 51-100)